# Is there a way in both OS X and Windows 7 to create a keyboard shortcut to launch a new instance of Chrome + on a speficic page?

Tags: google-chrome, hotkeys

So far I have not been able to find anything for either operating system (that doesn't require extensions to the browser or third party apps) that allows me to launch Chrome to a specific page. I see online that the workaround would be to set the home page to the desired page (the keyboard shortcut is the easy part of the question, for windows I can adjust the shortcut properties and on OS X I can use automator, I think).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7, find Chrome on the start menu, and make a copy of the shortcut.  Then in the properties of the new shortcut, you can set the hotkey using the `Shortcut key` field as you mentioned, and then simply put the URL just after a space after the .exe file.  Use that shortcut and it will open a new tab with your URL.

Comment: As for the other half of your question, see http://superuser.com/questions/291546/global-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-tab-in-chrome-on-mac-os-x except you can probably ignore much of the workaround since you DO want a URL unlike the OP there.