# Is there a way to set a system-wide keyboard shortcut to open a new chrome tab (and highlight the address bar) in Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a lot of really useful custom search engines in Chrome, as well as extensions that use the chrome omnibox. I do the following operation many times a day to access those search engines:

- Bring chrome to the front
- Open a new tab
- Type in my keyword and search term

Specifically selecting Chrome to bring to the front is by far the slowest part of that operation (that's because it's context-dependant - it depends on how many applications you have in front of it if you use alt-tab to tab through your open applications, or where your mouse is if you select chrome from your taskbar).

Far better would be to have a global keyboard shortcut that opens a new tab in Chrome from whatever you're doing and selects the omnibar. That would be completely context-free and you can let your muscle memory do the hard work.

Is there any way to configure this? Preferably natively in windows, but failing that with a Chrome extension.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/106890/how-can-i-use-autohotkey-to-focus-on-an-existing-google-chrome-tab-not-a-conta

  This should help

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the [same question was asked for OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/291546/global-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-tab-in-chrome-on-mac-os-x).

[w00t](https://superuser.com/users/5717/w00t)'s solution of using [a chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/global-new-tab-shortcut/dcngopenklmnfdlfocljeaokkhcplong?hl=en) with a global keyboard shortcut has the advantage of being OS-agnostic (and if I install it on Chrome on my windows machine I have it available on my Mac when I log in to my Chrome account).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what `OS` your using...

- `Windows` Will work.
- `Mac` will probably work.
- `Chrome OS` will eventually work.
- `Linux` Maybe? No test environment available for me.

  `Windows`: Download `Autohotkey` from [Here](https://autohotkey.com/download/) then look into custom `keyboard shortcuts`.

Your best bet to get this done on windows is to use the following code:

```
(Keyboard Function here):: run, "http://URL-example.com/*"
```

Working Example:

```
#noEnv
#persistent
$^a & n::
run, "http://google.com"
Return
```

Save as .ahk Then run and press `Ctrl`+`A`+`N` to test/use.

You can also compile this script into a `.exe` file using `ahk2exe.exe` found inside of `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Compiler`

That example opens `google.com` in your default browser on keyboard function: `Ctrl`+`A`+`N` (or `Ctrl`+`N`+`A`).

Now `chrome OS` users should be expecting `OS wide` `extension hot-keys` soon.

To make your extension have new tab capabilities just make the following files:

> Directory: `C:\Users\You\Documents\NewTabExtension..` -->
>
> Files:
>
> Manifest.json:

```
}
"name": "New Tab",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Press Alt+X to get started",

"browser_action": {
  "default_title": "New Tab",   
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"commands": {
  "_execute_browser_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "windows": "Alt+X",
      "mac": "Alt+X",
      "chromeos": "Alt+X",
      "linux": "Alt+X"
    }
  }
}

}
```

Change the parts after "`Windows`":, "`Linux`":, "`mac`":, And especially "`chromeos`": to whatever shortcut you want (Note: **CANNOT** be a built in browser function listed [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en))

> Popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

> popup.js:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].onload = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
```

This second method works for `chrome OS` and potentially `mac`, `windows`, & `linux` as long as they are allowed to be **ran in the background**. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577024/install-chrome-extension-not-in-the-store) for how to install your extension.

Last things last: `Mac OS`...

`Mac OS` ***Potentially*** will react fine to the extension option. However you must not `Command`+`Q` the window or else the shortcut will be null in void. I also know that `Mac OS` has a built in function for keyboard shortcut customization; However I am not familiar with that so you would have to mess around with that.